# How to assign value to an array, which is a struct member?

Tags: c++, g++

I define the following struct

```
struct CCPtDist
{
  double[] wDist = new double[8];
};
```

And I want to build a "CCPtDist" variable called tmpPtDist and want to assign a double number to wDist:

```
CCPtDist tmpPtDist;
tmpPtDist.wDist[0] = 233.7;
```

But the g++ compiler returns an error: ‘struct CCPtDist’ has no member named ‘wDist’?

Comment: I believe `double[] wDist = new double[8];` is a syntax error. Are you sure that's *exactly* what's in your code? Could it be `double* wDist = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong in the code. First off, if you declare an array as a member, the memory is allocated inline as part of the struct. You can't just assign an arbitrary pointer to it. Second off, I don't think you declared the array correctly anyway. Third, you need to put complex initialization like that in a constructor.
 I'm surprised it doesn't give you a compile error on the `double[] wDist = new double[8];`
 line.

Try changing it to something like this

```
struct CCPtDist
{
    double* wDist;

    CCPtDist(): wDist(new double[8]) {}
};
```

Comment: Better than this would be to make wDist be a `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: @Man only if you want to hold a variable number of elements. I think `std::array` would be best in this case.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to a C-style array, you can use `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

struct CCPtDist
{
  std::array<double,8> wDist;
};

int main()
{   
  CCPtDist tmpdist;
  tmpdist.wDist[0]=233.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed-size (!) array as part of your struct, there is no need for dynamic allocation (i.e. `new`):

```
struct CCPtDist
{
  double wDist[8];
};
```

will suffice. However, note that the 8 values of this array are not initialized this way. They will contain random garbage. So better add a constructor that initializes the array:

```
struct CCPtDist
{
  double wDist[8];
  CCPtDist():wDist() {}
};
```

If your compiler supports it, using `std::array`, which was introduced in C++11, might be a better approach, as described in SRN's answer.